# Ruby - cleanest way to return a value if truthy, or execute arbitrary code

Tags: ruby, performance, idioms

I'm coding something in Ruby where, given a value `foo` output from a method call, I want to:

- Return `foo` if `foo` is truthy
- Log an error and return a default value if `foo` is falsy.

The simplest naive way to implement this is probably:

```
foo = procedure(input)

if foo
  foo
else
  log_error
  default
end
```

but this feels overly verbose because `foo` is repeated three times, and this style is very imperative.

What's the cleanest, most idiomatic way to write this?

(Performance matters-- let's assume that `foo` is truthy in the vast majority of cases.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Living off of Ruby's Perl heritage:

```
foo = procedure(input) and return foo
log_error
default
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a rare case where Ruby's anonymous block is actually useful:

```
foo = procedure(input) || begin
  log_error
  default
end
```

Comment: Yes! For the sake of the community-at-large, it probably makes the most sense for me to accept the answer with the most votes, but this is exactly what I was personally looking for. I just tested this out, and it looks like you can write it without the assignment as well. I had no idea you could do this in Ruby. Out of curiosity, is it possible to write the anonymous block with `{ ... }` rather than `begin ... end`?

Comment: No, but you can use parens per @Arsen's answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can write that if `log_error` returns a true value

```
foo || log_error && default
```

If not:

```
foo || (log_error; default)
```

Comment: `foo || log_error; default` - will evaluate `foo || log_error;` as one statement and `default` as another - that may not be your intention.

Comment: I didn't realize you could group together Ruby statements like that (with parentheses), but it makes complete sense. POLA wins again! I wonder how it differs from a `begin`..`end` block?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness (and since no one has posted it yet) I'll add my original attempt at an answer:

```
procedure(input) || proc {
  log_error
  default
}.call
```

I can't think of any reason to use this over @mwp's answer:

```
procedure(input) || begin
  log_error
  default
end
```

because of the extra overhead (performance and readability) involved in creating the Proc object. Though some quick benchmarking reveals that the performance difference should be negligible in most cases, since the Proc object doesn't seem to be created unless `procedure(input)` is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

All things considered, I would go with:

```
foo = procedure(input)
return foo if foo
log_error
default
```